# .NET Core 2.1 watchdog for process termination

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, gpio

I'd like to be able to register something with the runtime at the launch of my process so that if the application is terminated, the runtime could run some type of "cleanup" for me.

I'm not talking about a try/finally, or an unhandled exception handler.  Here is the scenario.

I have a .NET 2.1 Core app running on Linux.  It access a GPIO pin to turn on a motor.  I then KILL the process.  Not a normal (please shutdown SIGTERM), but a SIGKILL (Kill (cannot be caught or ignored)).  In this case, the GPIO remains on and the motor is still running.

I've seen suggestions about running a script that does the actual launch and then resets the GPIO when it exists. That's sort of works, but seems like a hack.  I'd like to register a bit of code that the runtime could execute "as a bit of final cleanup" when the process exits.

Any ideas?

Comment: 4 years later... Did you find something about this ?